# What's a type of medication that people try and overdose on, but rarely works?

Tags: medical

I need to have a character try and kill themselves, be found latter and survive. Any ideas what drugs he would think would kill him but wouldn't actually?

Comment: VTC "Too story based".

Comment: Suicide by overdose has a relatively low success rate, which is why more girls attempt suicide,  but more boys succeed.

Comment: I don't see how this is about building a fictional world. It seems more like a real-world medicine question, or about the actions of an individual character. See [Help/on-topic].

Answer (score 10):

### Homeopathy

Homeopathy is an alternative medecine, proven to be no more effective than a placebo. However, not everyone is aware of that and some countries like France use it as a common medication. Your character is in this case: he **think** that homeopathy are medication, take lot of pills, some alcool, fall asleep due to alcool, but have nothing because they have no active substance

Fun fact: during the [10:23 Campaign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10:23_Campaign), some skeptics performed a "mass suicide stunt" with an overdose of homeopathically diluted snake poison, belladonna and arsenic, in an attempt to publicly show that homeopathy does not work

Comment: I have never heard people trying to overdose on homeopathic substances before. Never even occured to me. Interesting.

Comment: The guy that tried to homeopathically kill himself and even pass out on it is a great premise for a story, but it's not a great premise for any story. Those are the kind of answers why I love this place. Utter insanity, what a premise. i might steal this one if Woody Allen hasn't already turned this into a movie

Comment: There are in fact homeopathic "remedies" that warn users to call emergency services/poison control centres in case of an overdose. I think James Randi read the label in one of his talks somewhere.

Comment: I was going to propose placebo, but this is way better.  By the Law of Similars, homeopathically diluted mother's milk should be a good suicide potion.

Answer (score 6):

#### Sleeping pills

One major reason is that - at least where I come from - they are injected with a very tiny amount of something that makes you puke. Not noticable when you take a regular amount, but it is going to make you throw up if you take too many.

The purpose of this is to avoid lethal intake of sleeping pills, since they are one of the more common things suicidal people try to overdose on.

Comment: Sleeping pills aren't the only ones that have that substance added. I believe paracetamol/tylenol does too, and there are probably plenty of others.

Comment: @F1Krazy: yes, but that is the only one i am certain of. I do think most if not all painkillers have that, too. But i am not sure.

Comment: @Raditz_35: To my knowledge anything you could realistically overdose on regarding sleeping pills has that. There is obviously no need to put that in sugar pills.